# project from Geographic WGS84 to Mercator in R - points not finite

Tags: r, gis, map-projections

I am running into some projection issues in R that I do not understand.

I have downloaded the following global dataset:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/110m-land/

I then am creating maps using different projections to teach the concept of spatial projection.

I have successfully mapped and reprojected / mapped the data in lat/lon WGS84  and reprojected to Robinson

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
setwd("~/Documents/data")

# read shapefile
worldBound <- readOGR(dsn="Global/Boundaries/ne_110m_land", 
                layer="ne_110m_land")

# convert to dataframe
worldBound_df <- fortify(worldBound)  

# plot map
ggplot(worldBound_df, aes(long,lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  labs(title="World map (longlat)") +
  coord_equal() +
  ggtitle("Geographic - WGS84 Datum")

# reproject from longlat to robinson
worldBound_robin <- spTransform(worldBound,
                          CRS("+proj=robin"))
worldBound_df_robin <- fortify(wmap_robin)
ggplot(worldBound_df_robin, aes(long,lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  labs(title="World map (robinson)") +
  coord_equal()
```

Now - when i try to project to Mercator WGS84 i run into issues.

```
# reproject from longlat to mercator
worldBound_merc <- spTransform(worldBound,
                          CRS("+init=epsg:3395"))
# make ggplot happy
worldBound_df_merc <- fortify(worldBound_merc)
# plot map
ggplot(worldBound_df_merc, aes(long,lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  labs(title="World map (Mercator WGS84)") +
  coord_equal()
```

I get the error:
Error in .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  : 
  failure in Polygons 8 Polygon 1 points 
In addition: Warning message:
In .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  :
  2 projected point(s) not finite

The error is on the spTransform function. It almost seems as if it can not calculate a finite xy coordinate from lat long to mercator for some points but i don't understand how to fix /address this. My searches on this site and others have resulted in other instances of this error, but not a good explanation of what triggers the error when projecting the data so i can fix it.

Thank you for any guidance!
Leah

---

Resolution Code:
For those who run into this - i just cropped the data to be able to plot using Mercator. This is just a demonstration so it's ok to lose some of the data for visual, mapping purposes.

```
# create extent object from world data
newExt <- extent(worldBound)
# redefine the extent to the limits of mercator EPSG 3395
newExt@ymin <- -80
newExt@ymax <- 80

# crop data to new extent
merc_WorldBound <- crop(worldBound,
                        newExt)

# reproject from longlat to mercator
worldBound_merc <- spTransform(merc_WorldBound,
                          CRS("+init=epsg:3395"))
```

Comment: Does your dataset have points/vertices at the north and south poles? These points are not defined in a Mercator projection and might be infinite.

Comment: it does! Gosh I didn't think to check the lat-long boundaries of Mercator. Ok so i'll adjust those to be within the 82 degree range north and south and will try to project again! THANK YOU. that makes sense and is likely the culprit.

Comment: is there an efficient want to scale all coordinates in the spatial data frame >82 to equal 82? I am trying to think about a creative way to address this issue.

Comment: To me it doesn't make sense to shift points to 82 degrees if they are beyond. What would be the physical justification?

Comment: Very true. I was just thinking it makes more sense to just crop the data for this demonstration . Thank you!!

Comment: i've added the final code to the above question for those who may come across this in their search. Thank you so much for the input. I wasn't thinking straight in terms of adjusting the data - or perhaps i was thinking too much :) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue appears to be points that lie outside the bounds of the epsg:3395 projection (-180, -80, 180, 84) http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-world-mercator/. To correct this you can clip the shapefile to an appropriate extent and then perform the reprojection.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
worldBoundClipped <- crop(worldBound,extent(-180,180,-84,80))
worldBound_merc <- spTransform(worldBoundClipped,CRS("+init=epsg:3395"))
```